# Splash Screen in iOS mobile apps(Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, mobile-application

I want to implement splash screen for my ios app with a delay of about 2-3 seconds.I am using Swift language for programming.How can I implement this.
Any suggestion will be really helpful.

Comment: Please, post what have you searched and/or tried so far.

Comment: you can use launch screen  as Splash by adding delay sleep(3) at didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Add Delay time in App didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

//For Swift 3.0
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

          Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 2.0)//2.0 Delay Time

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The splash screen should only be static and should not have associated viewController 
[source](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/launch-screen/)

Instead of letting the splash screen sleep, you should segue immediately to another view with an associated view controller. In that you can make something animate or whatever you want(show this for 3 seconds as you wanted, though I don't recommend it. **Start your app as quick as possible**. Don't make delays on the Main thread)

Here's something you can do:

Lunch Screen(Splash screen) -> view(delay 2 seconds) -> main view

Though if you really want to make a delay you can do as the others here have mentioned:

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in fact with [Thread](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/thread) [sleep(forTimeInterval ti: TimeInterval)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/thread/1413673-sleep)

For example, try this in your [AppDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate) [didFinishLaunchingWithOptions](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622921-application):

```
Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 2) // 2 seconds
```

I hope my answer was helpful